# Abandoned cart item options

Tags: cart

I have a code for getting abandoned cart details:

```
$quotes = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
    foreach ($quotes as $quote) {
        $itemsCollection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($itemsCollection as $item) {
            //Getting item info
        }
    }
```

But how can I get item options(Color:Green, Size:L, etc..) ?

Answer (score 1):

call `$item->getOptions()`

This will return an array for the options for the quote item. You could then do something like:

```
$options = array();
foreach($item->getOptions() as $option){
$options[$option->getLabel] = $option->getValue()
}
```

Note: $option->getValue() would return an ID instead of a label for drop down type custom options; so you may have to loop on $option->getValues() to be able to map an id to it's label.

Comment: thx, I'd already tried so... This code works on retrieving options for typical order. But in case of abandoned cart we get differ result:
72 => 72;
227 => 227